# Auto Save in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there an Auto Save feature in Visual Studio 2022? [The article here](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-now-autosave-files-in-visual-studio-2022/) says it is.

But for me I dont see it. Is it removed in Preview? Or I am missing something?

[image: Tools Options in Visual Stuion 2022]

Comment: You'd need at least version 17.1, preview 2.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#1710-pre20--visual-studio-2022-version-171-preview-2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

had the same issue
found solution,
download this extension: [AutoSave extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HRai.AutoSaveFile)
and install it.
you can find the setting under **Tools -> Options -> Auto Save File**

Here's a picture

[image: Visual Studio Auto Save extension Settings]

Comment: I have installed this extension and it works fine, except when I use Intellisense or a refactoring tool, after "Time Delay' it will exit the intellisense/refactor prompt.  e.g. if i'm scrolling throuhg a list of functions, I lose them after $TIME_DELAY seconds

Answer (score 17):

With Visual Studio 2022 17.2.2 version, this option is now available at
**Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents**.

https://www.talkingdotnet.com/auto-save-files-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: Unfortunately the option is "Save when Visual Studio is in background", that is, when you switch to another application. It doesn't save as you type like VS Code does. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin supported by VSIX named: Auto Save File.
Menu "Extension"...
[image: plugin view]

Default time is 5 s.

Edit 1: the only default I see with this plugin is that you must be very quick when using the VS autocomplete feature (when writing the code), because it will reset every 5 seconds!